# rsync "Operation not permitted (1)" error only when run in launchd

Tags: launchd

### Context

There is a similar question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/369988/rsync-errors-but-only-when-run-in-launchd), however I feel the answer does not expand on how to "invoke the user environment profile from the launchd script"; and the alternative solution of identifying differences in the user and launchd environments shouldn't apply since I am running a launchd agent (run within user context) and not a launchd daemon (run within system context).

### My setup

I have a `run_rsync_back.sh` file in my home directory with the following (**note that this script runs sucessfully when manually run from the terminal**):

```
date >> ~/.cron.log && rsync --stats -hai --delete /Users/username/Documents/ username@server.net:/home/username/Documents_MacbookPro/ >> ~/.backup.log 2>&1
```

I have ensured the above file is executable with `chmod +x`
And created a launchd Property List file for my agent:
~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.rsyncbackup.plist

with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.rsyncbackup</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/Users/username/.run_rsync_backup.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>7200</integer>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

After starting the daemon (`launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.rsyncbackup.plist`), I can confirm that nothing was transferred to the server, and the following error appears in the `~/.backup.log` file:

```
Sat Aug 29 17:19:16 CEST 2020
rsync: [sender] opendir "/Users/username/Documents/." failed: Operation not permitted (1)
IO error encountered -- skipping file deletion

Number of files: 1 (dir: 1)
Number of created files: 0
Number of deleted files: 0
Number of regular files transferred: 0
Total file size: 0 bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 0
File list generation time: 0.015 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 67
Total bytes received: 70

sent 67 bytes  received 70 bytes  274.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1307) [sender=3.2.2]
```

I have also tried the above on an out-of-the-box Mac, with exactly the same result!

Comment: Check the answers to ["How to run a LaunchAgent that runs a script which causes failures because of System Integrity Protection"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338213/how-to-run-a-launchagent-that-runs-a-script-which-causes-failures-because-of-sys) (note: it's actually Transparency Consent and Control, not really SIP, that's limiting access).

Comment: @GordonDavisson: thanks for pointing me to that. Channing's answer (https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/338214/387826): allowing bash to have full access, finally solved the problem.

Comment: Sorry, that second comment appeared automatically when I recommended this question be marked as a duplicate of the other. I'll delete it.