# Give the Terminal.app Full Disk permission problem even it is given

Tags: terminal, security, bash, launchd, trash

macOS: v 11.2.3
Chip Apple M1

I have given the Full Disk Access to Terminal and iTerm.

[image]

But when I run a Bash script to clean up the Trash directory I get "Give the Terminal.app Full Disk permission in the Security settings." error.
When I run for Downloads directory, I don't have any problems.

I run this script through launchd plist file.
I restarted the mac.

What can I do to avoid this error?

Comment: You're running the script through launchd.  Terminal.app is not involved so the permissions Terminal.app might have are not relevant.  What problem are you actually trying to solve by running this script vs letting the OS manage it?

Comment: Does [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338213/how-to-run-a-launchagent-that-runs-a-script-which-causes-failures-because-of-sys) (or any of the ones linked to it) solve your problem?