# Run Shell Scripts on a Schedule

Tags: launchd, cron, macos

Is there "a right" way to run shell scripts on a schedule in modern versions of MacOS?  My usual go to for this has been using the `cron` command -- but [recent changes make seem like](https://osxdaily.com/2020/04/27/fix-cron-permissions-macos-full-disk-access/) this isn't in the front of Apple's mind these days.

Is there a better option than cron for running programs on a schedule in modern (Big Sur era) MacOS?  Is my only option biting the bullet and learning how `launchd` works or is there something simpler/easier that I can use?

Comment: **Apple** recommends using `launchd` and while it's a bit of a handful learning it from the various _manual pages_ around it, `launchctl`, `launchd.plist` and `launchd`, there are _third-party applications_ that present a **GUI** interface to it. One of which that I've used in the past is [Lingon](https://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/), however there are a few more of them out there.

Comment: `launchd` jobs are subject to the same permissions restrictions as `cron` jobs (see ["How to run a LaunchAgent that runs a script which causes failures because of System Integrity Protection"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338213/how-to-run-a-launchagent-that-runs-a-script-which-causes-failures-because-of-sys), for example). Personally, I don't see any great need to switch from `cron`, if that's what you're more comfortable with (at least at this point). But if you do need to switch, `launchd` is definitely the system to switch to.

Comment: That's good to know @GordonDavisson -- this particular question was prompted by an issue with setting up a new cron job that was silently failing, leaving me guessing as to what was causing the failure and being unable to rule out System Integrity Protection (even though a second cron job is running fine). If launchd suffers the same sorts of issues that's good to know.  A bummer, but still good to know.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a “right” way from Apple’s point of view, then it’s `launchd`. Not that `cron` is “wrong” *per se* but it is not the “preferred” way.

However, as you indicated, `launchd` can be a pain to work with.

There are two good apps to try:

1. https://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/ ¹
2. https://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/

Lingon has been around for a long time and is probably better known, but I switched to LaunchControl a few years ago and much prefer it.

The developer also maintains https://launchd.info which is a helpful tutorial website to understand how `launchd` works.

LaunchControl also has a built-in tool that can mitigate issues around Full Disk Access, making it easier to deal with macOS' restrictions.

---

There is another, simpler option: [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/). Not only does Keyboard Maestro have a feature to run scripts (or macros, etc) at a specific time or recurring every X minutes, but **you can also use cron-style syntax** if you want.

Given that Keyboard Maestro is the best automation tool for the Mac, and I'd probably sacrifice a finger rather than be forced to use a Mac without it, you can guess that I strongly recommend Keyboard Maestro. It has a free trial (for other 2 weeks or 30 days, I'm not sure, but it's definitely a long time) and is actively maintained.

---

¹ As of this writing, both the LaunchControl website and launchd.info site appear to be down, which I assume is just a temporary glitch. They were working as recently as last night. If it is still down when you read this, you can download a copy of the latest version (which also has a free trial) from my website here:

https://iusethis.luo.ma/launchcontrol/LaunchControl-1.52.3.tbz2

Answer (score 2):

You can still use `crontab` in the same way as you do it on a linux box — MacOS does not run a real `cron` service and `crontab` is just a wrapper that delegates to `launchd` saving you the need to bother with the [launchd XML syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) (see under *Running a Job Periodically*).

Go ahead and create your cron entries using the [familiar syntax](https://crontab.guru/every-day-8am) by running as your regular user:

```bash
crontab -e
```

**NOTE**: You can also use `sudo crontab -e` if your task needs to be run as root. You need to make sure that the root user has access to your script though.

*Example entry:*

```
0 8 * * * /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh >> /tmp/myscript_errors.log 2>&1
```

List existing `crontab` entries:

```bash
crontab -l
```

When cron jobs generate output MacOS creates local mail entries which could show up as `You have new mail` notifications when you open a new terminal shell. To disable local mail messages add to the top of your crontab the following line:

```bash
MAILTO=""
```

PS: Depending on the version of your MacOS you might need to allow full disc access to `/usr/bin/crontab` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60523149/191246).

Comment: macOS does run a "real" `cron` daemon ([Paul Vixie's implementation, though it's a pretty old version](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/cron/blob/cron-42/cron/cron.c)). launchd does supervise the `cron` daemon, and is configured to run it only when at least one crontab file exists. So it'd be more accurate to say that launchd delegates crontabs to the `cron` daemon.