# Can't use System Events when using Launch Daemons and Agents

Tags: terminal, applescript, permission, launchd, accessibility

I'm writing a little Go program that uses osascript (based on [mac2mqtt](https://github.com/bessarabov/mac2mqtt/blob/ece79452a91c10027043e81077d9674b1cf6b655/mac2mqtt.go)):

```go
func getCommandOutput(name string, arg ...string) string {
    var outbuf, errbuf strings.Builder // or bytes.Buffer
    cmd := exec.Command(name, arg...)
    cmd.Stdout = &outbuf
    cmd.Stderr = &errbuf

    err := cmd.Run();

    stdout := outbuf.String()
    stderr := errbuf.String()

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(stderr)
        log.Fatal(stderr)
    }

    return strings.TrimSuffix(stdout, "\n")
}

func main() {
    runCommand("/usr/bin/osascript", "-e", "tell application \"zoom.us\"", "-e", "tell application \"System Events\"", "-e", "keystroke \"a\" using {shift down, command down}", "-e", "end tell", "-e", "end tell")
}
```

After compiling this code into a file called `mac2mqttzoom` I get an executable. I run `chmod +x mac2mqttzoom`, run it from Visual Studio Code, and get this dialog:

[image]

I hit OK and all is good. Then I create a LaunchAgent file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.adriaan.mac2mqttzoom</string>
        <key>Program</key>
        <string>/Users/adriaan/mac2mqtt/mac2mqttzoom</string>
        <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
        <string>/Users/adriaan/mac2mqtt/</string>
        <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/Users/adriaan/mac2mqtt/standard.log</string>
        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/Users/adriaan/mac2mqtt/error.log</string>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

But when I run this program I get this error:

```
System Events got an error: osascript is not allowed assistive access. (-25211)
```

Only when running with Launch Daemons and Agents.

I gave permission via Acccessibility to all relevant apps:

[image]

Comment: Granting access to launch agents is messy and unintuitive); the answers to ["How to run a LaunchAgent that runs a script which causes failures because of System Integrity Protection"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338213/how-to-run-a-launchagent-that-runs-a-script-which-causes-failures-because-of-sys) might help (but note: it's properly TCC, not SIP, that's enforcing these restrictions).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, @gordon-davisson for guiding me in the right direction.

I moved my `plist`-file to `/Library/LaunchDaemons/` and readded my binary to the Accesibility apps in System Preferences:

[image]

You need to do this every time your binary changes. I didn't do that before. So for everybody that encounters this issue as well:

1. Update your own app/binary
2. Remove it from the Accessibility list
3. Add it back to the list (via the <kbd>+</kbd> or drag and drop)
4. Unload & load your app again

   - `sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/your.app.plist`
   - `sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/your.app.plist`