# launchd job returning 2 but works fine in terminal

Tags: bash, permission, launchd, python

I'm trying to write a bash script to clean up my Downloads folder every day at a certain time. The bash script should get called then a python program afterwards to do the cleanup.

I'm using `launchd` to schedule the job but the job status code keeps returning as 2. I ran the executable of my bash script in the root directory as `/Users/aabdi/Library/Scripts/clean.sh` and it works fine. But when I load the file into `launchctl` I get a error code of 2.

Also the plist file is in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` and when running `putil` on it returned 'OK'. My question is the error code states "No such file or directory" but it exists. Is there some sort of security permission on the Downloads folder?

plist file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.aabdibot.cleandownloads</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Users/aabdi/Library/Scripts/clean.sh</string>
  <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
  <dict>
    <key>PATH</key>
    <string>/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin</string>
  </dict>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
  <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
  <dict>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>4</integer>
    <key>Minute</key>
    <integer>30</integer>
  </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

bash script

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Go to directory
cd /Users/aabdi/Downloads/

#print directory
echo "$PWD"

#run python script
python3 clean.py
```

Python script

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os 
from pathlib import Path

os.system("cd /Users/aabdi/Downloads")

for x in os.listdir():
    tup = os.path.splitext(x)
    file_name = tup[0]
    ext_name = tup[1].lower()

    if os.path.isdir(x) or ext_name == '' or ext_name == '.py' or ext_name == '.zsh':
        continue
    
    cur_path = os.getcwd()
    ext_name = ext_name.replace(ext_name[0], "", 1)
    fin_path = cur_path + "/" + ext_name 

    print(f"folder is {fin_path}")
    
    if os.path.isdir(fin_path) == False:
        os.mkdir(fin_path)

    cur_path = cur_path + "/" + x
    fin_path = fin_path + "/" + x
    
    os.rename(cur_path,fin_path)
    print(f"Moved {x}\n")
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm no good with plists, `launchd`, etc, BUT I do use [`LaunchControl`](https://soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/) extensively. A great utility IMHO.

Comment: Check /var/log/com.apple.xpc.launchd/launchd.log

Comment: I checked the log in Launch Control, it might be similar since it gives info for that specific job. It only gave me this ```exited due to exit(2)\n internal event: EXITED, code = 0```.

Comment: Where is python3 installed? Does it help to call python3 with an absolute path from the shell script?

Comment: Your Downloads folder is subject to privacy protection by the TCC (Transparency, Consent, and Control) system, so you probably need to grant the launchd item access to it. See [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338213/how-to-run-a-launchagent-that-runs-a-script-which-causes-failures-because-of-sys) (but note that you only want to grant access to Downloads, not Full Disk Access). Also, running `cd` via `os.system()` won't do anything useful, and when you run it in a script, you should always include an error check in case it fails (like it's doing here).

Comment: Can you grant that within Settings. The Full Disk Access tab in settings lets you add applications to it. But the Files and Folder tab only works if the app requests it.